# Как установить драйвера для адаптера tp-link archer t4u на linux?

Tags: wifi, virtualbox, драйвер, kali-linux

Купил адаптер Archer t4u от компании tp-link. На сайте магазина в характеристике выбранного товара написано, что поддерживает операционные системы Windows, Mac, Linux, но на самой коробке адаптера про линукс не написано ни слова... Скачал с официального сайта производителя инструкцию по установке драйвера и собственно сам драйвер (https://www.tp-link.com/ru/support/download/archer-t4u/#Driver), выполнил пошагово все действия указанные в ней, но драйер все равно не устанавливается..
термина выдает следующие ошибки:

```
make[3]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-kali7-common/scripts/Makefile.build:284: /home/jhondoe/Desktop/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-kali7-common/Makefile:1822: /home/jhondoe/Desktop/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta] Error 2
make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-kali7-common/Makefile:185: __sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-kali7-amd64'
make: *** [Makefile:1998: modules] Error 2
```

как можно  решить эту проблему? В линуксе полный профан, поэтому прошу объяснить как для десятилетнего ребенка) спасибо заранее..

Comment: а перед этим какие сообщения?

Answer (score 1):

Вроде у него чипсет - `RTL8814AU`

```
sudo apt install dkms build-essential libelf-dev linux-headers-`uname -r`
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8814au
cd rtl8814au
sudo make dkms_install
```

Если не поможет то отсюда скачать драйвера: https://github.com/morrownr/8814au и следуйте инструкции установки.